# use window.AudioContext without window object

Tags: javascript

I am using the Java Scripting API to run some javascript for audio. The js file uses "window.AudioContext" (a function), but when I run the program, it throws an error about window not existing. All I need is window.AudioContext, so is there some way that I can get that function and specifically implement it manually?
- For example, I would declare my own function AudioContext that creates the same object as window.AudioContext and use that instead, I just don't know how to get the declaration for window.AudioContext

```
var contextClass = window.AudioContext;
this.audioCtx = new contextClass();
```

The computer throws the error on the "var contextClass"

Comment: AudioContext is defined in the [WebAudio API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/). Theoretically, you could implement the API in your non-browser context (or more likely, borrow an existing implementation from a browser codebase).

Comment: I can't find any declarations for the WebAudio API. Where would I find a codebase for that?

Comment: My link points to the spec ; there is no single implementation of it. Like I said, look at an open-source Web browser of your choice. WebAudio is not going to be 50 lines of code you can copy-paste, it's a complete API for digital signal processing. You'll probably see thousands of lines, with bindings to OS-specific audio libraries.